# Kivy.Uix.Sandbox implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I've been looking around for how to use the Sandbox, but I can't find examples of proper usage of the Class. Best I've found is the [kivy api](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.sandbox.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SandBox is still in alpha stage, which is why you can't find any good documentation about it. It's not ready for real use yet.

From [the api](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.sandbox.html):

> The SandBox widget is still experimental... 
>   Don’t use it unless you know what you are doing :)

However, if you want to try to play with it anyway, I'd recommend looking at the [Kivy designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer) project to see how it's used there.